# Trim factor labels for multiple variables at the same time

Tags: r, dplyr, forcats

This is my toy dataset:

```r
 library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble (x1 = c("False - very long label specific to x1", "False - very long label specific to x1", "True - very long label specific to x1", "True - very long label specific to x1"),
               x2 = c("False - very long label specific to x2", "False - very long label specific to x2", "False - very long label specific to x2", "True - very long label specific to x2"),
               y = c(10, 5, 12, 4)) %>% mutate_at(vars(x1:x2), factor)
head(dat)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   x1                                x2                                    y
#>   <fct>                             <fct>                             <dbl>
#> 1 False - very long label specific~ False - very long label specific~    10
#> 2 False - very long label specific~ False - very long label specific~     5
#> 3 True - very long label specific ~ False - very long label specific~    12
#> 4 True - very long label specific ~ True - very long label specific ~     4
```

I would like to trim the very long factor labels, they all have two things in common:

1. all start with *True* or *False*
2. include the column name (ie the factor labels for each column are unique)

I would like to simplify this, and have only something like *True* and *False* for each factor column. This is my desired output:

```r
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   x1    x2        y
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 False False    10
#> 2 False False     5
#> 3 True  False    12
#> 4 True  True      4
```

I think it should work with something like `mutate_at` and `fct_relabel` and maybe `str_trunc`, but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `trimws` with `whitespace`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, ~ factor(trimws(., whitespace = "\\s*-.*")))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  x1    x2        y
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#1 False False    10
#2 False False     5
#3 True  False    12
#4 True  True      4
```

---

Or with `fct_relabel` and `str_remove`

```
library(forcats)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
    mutate_if(is.factor, ~ fct_relabel(., ~str_remove(., '\\s*-.*')))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
m1 <- names(which(sapply(dat, is.factor)))
setDT(dat)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        factor(sub('\\s*-.*', "", x))) , .SDcols = nm1]
```

Comment: both work great on the toy dataset, but my full dataset is relatively large. The first solution crashed my R session with the full dataset, and the second solution works but takes a long time. any suggestions for speeding up the process would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @Esther Can you try it on `data.table` `library(data.table);nm1 <- names(which(sapply(dat, is.factor))); setDT(dat)[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(sub('\\s*-.*', "", x))) , .SDcols = nm1]`